# Capistrano: exit inside 'on roles' block

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

This task work:

```
before :publishing, :execute do
  exit
end
```

But this not:

```
before :publishing, :execute do
  on roles(:web) do
    exit
  end
end
```

It says something like:

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: exit

SystemExit: exit

Tasks: TOP => deploy:publishing => deploy:execute
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deployer@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: exit
```

I need to run exit inside the `on roles(:web)` block (because the system exit basing on assumptions and conditionals).

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks